# SQL Server checksum in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, checksum

I have a table in SQL Server like this :

**Users** :

```
int ID PK Identity
nvarchar(50) Username
nvarchar(50) Password
```

I stored the checksum string in the `Password` column and use this method to hash password and the stored them in my table

Now I want to use this table in EF like this ;

```
User = DBContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(rec => rec.Username == Request["U"] && rec.Password == Request["P"]);
```

but because I stored the checksum values in my table, so I must to change `Request["P"]` to use it in EF

Sorry I am new in English, did you find out what it I talking about it ? (I hope I could explain my problem clearly :( )

**UPDATE1** : If I have a query like this :

```
Select * from Users where username = @p1 and password = checksum(@p2)
```

how I convert @p2 to use that query like this :

```
Select * from Users where username = @p1 and password = @p2 --Checksum omitted
```

Comment: Did you mean this CHECKSUM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx?

Comment: @Dennis , yes , the checksum we use in sql server :) , look at UPDATE1

Comment: Are you using Code First approach with EF?

Comment: @Dennis , No I am using Database First approach dude

Comment: Use system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.checksum In Your LINQ Expression https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.checksum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you're using Database First (this means that you have EDMX), you can add [custom function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456812.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(@password)
```

to you EDMX, and then you may call it to calculate checksum value for the password before using password in a LINQ query.

Comment: I was creating a stored procedure not exactly like that you said but it work like some thing like your idea and although you answered me late and I solved my problem but your answer (or better your idea) is correct one hundred percent and I accept it gladly and thanks for you attention , you are a great man and thanks again dude